# MongoDB: drop duplicates based on fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have many duplicate entries in my Mongo Database. Is there a quick way to remove these duplicates?
I am interested in two different scenarios:

1. For duplicate entries each of the fields are equal (except ObjectID)
2. For duplicate entries only a subset of all the fields are equal. In this case, I would like to specify those fields and drop the duplicates based on them.

What is the "mongoic" way of doing this?

An example entry would be:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318e"),
"category" : "house",
"city" : "Boston",
"title" : "title here",
"url" : "http://url.com",
"text" : " some text here",
"time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
"user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
"price_eur" : 85000
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample documents and the results you're expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a js script you can use to achieve this:

```
var matchingId = [];

db.collectionName.aggregate([
   {
      // group stage: group document by field 
      // this return one document per unique value
      $group:{
         _id:{
            category:"$category",
            city:"$city"
        // ...
        // here add as many field as you want for duplicate check
         },
         // this field count the number of documents having the same 
         // values for the selected fields
         count:{
            $sum:1
         },
         // this field store the _id of documents that have the same 
         // value for selected fields  
         match:{
            $push:"$_id"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      // only keep documents where count > 1
      $match:{
         count:{
            $gt:1
         }
      }
   }], 
   {
      // allow mongoDB to write to disk if your collection is too big
      allowDiskUse: true
   } 
).forEach( function(doc) {
   doc.match.shift(); // remove the first objectId
   doc.match.forEach( function(duplicateId) {
   matchingId.push(duplicateId);
   });
});

// remove duplicate documents
db.collectionName.remove({_id: {$in: matchingId}})
```

to use it write this to a file named "script.js" and use it like this from your terminal:

```
mongo databaseName < script.js
```

you should try it on a test database to make sure it behaves as you want!

**edit: example**

let's say your collection looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318e"),
    "category" : "house",
    "city" : "Boston",
    "title" : "title here",
    "url" : "http://url.com",
    "text" : " some text here",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
    "user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "price_eur" : 85000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318b"),
    "category" : "house",
    "city" : "NY",
    "title" : "title here",
    "url" : "http://url.com",
    "text" : " some text here",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
    "user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "price_eur" : 85000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318f"),
    "category" : "house",
    "city" : "Boston",
    "title" : "title here",
    "url" : "http://url.com",
    "text" : " some text here",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
    "user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "price_eur" : 85000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318c"),
    "category" : "house",
    "city" : "Boston",
    "title" : "title here",
    "url" : "http://url.com",
    "text" : " some text here",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
    "user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "price_eur" : 85000
}
```

the output of the aggregation query will be

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "category" : "house",
        "city" : "Boston"
    },
    "count" : 3,
    "match" : [
        ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318e"),
        ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318f"),
        ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318c")
    ]
}
```

so you iterate over the results and for each documents you remove the first _id (as you need to keep one document among the duplicates) with match.shift()
and then store the other _ids so you can remove corresponding documents

after running the script the collection contains only those documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318e"),
    "category" : "house",
    "city" : "Boston",
    "title" : "title here",
    "url" : "http://url.com",
    "text" : " some text here",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
    "user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "price_eur" : 85000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57294d7071f55974cdae318b"),
    "category" : "house",
    "city" : "NY",
    "title" : "title here",
    "url" : "http://url.com",
    "text" : " some text here",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-05-03T23:49:00Z"),
    "user_online_since" : ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "price_eur" : 85000
}
```

Comment: thank you. Could you pls explain a little what is going on?

Comment: @Botond see my edit